# How do I delete all directories matching a pattern using SVN?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have checked in a huge Eclipse project from my desktop computer to the SVN server.  I did it using the command line.  However, by mistake I committed all the compiled classes also in the server.

For every plug-in, there is a directory /bin/ that contains the compiled classes.

Is there a way to quickly delete in the server all directories that match this pattern using the command line?

Additionally, is there a way to tell svn to ignore bin directories by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](http://bugs.sakaiproject.org/confluence/display/BOOT/Add+bin+and+target+to+global+svn+ignore+in+Eclipse) (for the 'additionally part'):

1. Click on Window -> Preferences
2. Select Team -> Ignored Resources
3. Click on Add Pattern and enter "bin"
4. Click on Apply and then OK

For the bin directories, do you have svn 1.5 ?

Because if you do, `'svn rm --keep-local'` allows to pull them from version control but *not* delete it from your machine.

You can do it with **[Tortoise](http://www.thecrumb.com/2008/07/14/digging-into-tortoisesvn/)** (Delete (keep local))

Answer (score 2):

To add to what VonC suggests, if you're using the command line, you can edit your configuration file (and change your global-ignores entry) here:

```
~/.subversion/config
```

or in the windows registry:

```
HKCU\Software\Tigris.org\Config
```